# C# dbcontext return error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

When I only select one field, it works fine, but when I use 2 fields to return, it
errors.

Error: The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

```
var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT source, text FROM dbo.USA").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reading your result into a string object, but returning multiple results, you need to read it into an object that maps these properties.

You can create a class like

```
public class Country {
   public string Source {get; set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}

}
```

And then call

```
var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<Country>("SELECT source, text FROM dbo.USA").ToList();
```